# algorithm to convert 2D coordinates to 2.5D

Tags: algorithm

I have vector street map data in 2D format as below:

polyline0:
dataX = {x00,x01,..,x0n}
dataY = {y00,y01,..,y0n}

polyline1:
dataX = {x10,x11,..,x1n}
dataY = {y10,y11,..,y1n}

polyline2:
dataX = {x20,x21,..,x2n}
dataY = {y20,y21,..,y2n}

...

polylinem:
dataX = {xm0,xm1,..,xmn}
dataY = {ym0,ym1,..,ymn}

I can draw polyline0, polyline1,.., polylinem on screen as top down view (2D).

Now I want to draw polyline0, polyline1,.., polylinem on screen as 2.5D view (either perspective projection or isometric projection)

I am looking for algorithm to convert 2D coordinates to 2.5D. I tried to search for this algorithm on the internet but could not find.

What I am looking is just a simple formula that allow me to convert the above 2D data to 2.5D data as below:

take polyline0 as example:
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  dataX[i] in 2.5D = convert2Dto2.5D(dataX[i] in 2D);
  dataY[i] in 2.5D = convert2Dto2.5D(dataY[i] in 2D);
}

I am looking for your help and greatly appreciated your time to help me with a algorithm to convert 2D coordinates to 2.5D.

Comment: 2.5D? Is that what people call projected 3D nowadays?

Comment: What the heck is 2.5D? You'll have to define that.

Comment: Seems your answer is here (duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647532/problem-with-birds-eye-view-or-2-5d-rendering-of-map

Answer (score 1):

For the commenters, [2.5D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D) is described here.

The [isometric projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) looks pretty straightforward to implement. The math becomes simpler with the restrictions you have.

The z coordinate of the points on the lines is always 0, so the product of the matrices on that wikipedia page is just

```
newx = 1 / sqrt(2) * oldx;
newy = 1 / sqrt(6) * (oldx + 2 * oldy);
```

or

```
newx = oldx;
newy = 1 / sqrt(3) * (oldx + 2 * oldy);
```

if you don't mind the scaling.

Other isometric views can be worked out from the source above.

Comment: Thanks UncleO, I modified your formula a bit to make it work with integer: newx = 1000*oldx/1414;  newy = 1000*(oldx + 2*oldy)/2449;

Comment: newx = 1000*oldx/1414;  newy = 1000*(oldx + 2*oldy)/2449;

Comment: However, when I apply that formula, the result is not what I want. What I want is to convert 2D vector street map like this picture http://androinica-serve.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/copilot_mapmodes_2dnextturn.png to 2.5D or 3D like this picture http://pocketnow.com/html/portal/news/0000010736//340x_scrobble.jpg